# Parsing only data tags that contain a specific string pattern

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to parse data tags "td" that contain the string of a regex pattern. A sample td that contains such a string is "/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619419000004/0001446194-19-000004-index.htm".

I have tried to use re.compile and a regex expression with "td:contains"

```
a=list()

url = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?filenum=028-13216&action=getcompany"
r =requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')
table = soup.find("table",{"class":"tableFile2"})
rows = table.find_all("tr")

text_main='<[a-z]{2} [a-z]{7}="[a-z]{7}"><[a-z] [a-z]{4}="/\w/\w/\w/\d{7}/\d{18}/\d{10}-\d{2}-\d{6}-\w.[a-z]{3}" [a-z]{2}'

for i in rows:
    a.append(i.find_all(f'td:contains({re.compile(text_main)})'))
)'))
```

a just consists of an empty list of list

Comment: That's because `i.find_all(f'td:contains({re.compile(text_main)})')` returns a blank list.

Comment: @Eli so how could I find data tags with a specific string pattern?

Comment: Why don't you just get the href of the a tag in the td?

Comment: @Eli i tried that but the same result persisted

Comment: Why don't you just regex the whole text instead of using find/find_all

Comment: I tested your regex pattern on r.text and it returns None. Your regex pattern is incorrect

Comment: What are you trying to pull out of the page HTML with this regex? It will match `<** *******...` meaning (less than) two letters (space) seven letters, but there aren't actuallly any lines with that pattern in the HTML

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regular expression is not required.Try the following code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

a=[]
url = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?filenum=028-13216&action=getcompany"
r =requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one(".tableFile2")


for i in table.select("td[nowrap='nowrap']"):
   if i.select_one('a#documentsbutton'):
     a.append(i.select_one('a#documentsbutton')['href'])

print(a)
```

Output:

```
['/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619419000004/0001446194-19-000004-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619419000003/0001446194-19-000003-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619418000008/0001446194-18-000008-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619418000007/0001446194-18-000007-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619418000005/0001446194-18-000005-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619418000002/0001446194-18-000002-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619417000017/0001446194-17-000017-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619417000010/0001446194-17-000010-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619417000008/0001446194-17-000008-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619417000006/0001446194-17-000006-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619417000002/0001446194-17-000002-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619416000016/0001446194-16-000016-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619416000014/0001446194-16-000014-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619416000013/0001446194-16-000013-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619416000012/0001446194-16-000012-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619416000009/0001446194-16-000009-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619415000008/0001446194-15-000008-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619415000006/0001446194-15-000006-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000113630515000010/0001136305-15-000010-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619415000002/0001446194-15-000002-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619414000013/0001446194-14-000013-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619414000009/0001446194-14-000009-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619414000007/0001446194-14-000007-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619414000001/0001446194-14-000001-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619413000053/0001446194-13-000053-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619413000050/0001446194-13-000050-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619413000013/0001446194-13-000013-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619413000002/0001446194-13-000002-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619412000034/0001446194-12-000034-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619412000024/0001446194-12-000024-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619412000013/0001446194-12-000013-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619412000002/0001446194-12-000002-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000091895011000005/0000918950-11-000005-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619411000004/0001446194-11-000004-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619411000003/0001446194-11-000003-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619411000002/0001446194-11-000002-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619411000001/0001446194-11-000001-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619410000014/0001446194-10-000014-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619410000013/0001446194-10-000013-index.htm', '/Archives/edgar/data/1446194/000144619410000011/0001446194-10-000011-index.htm']
```

---

Or you can use this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

a=[]
url = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?filenum=028-13216&action=getcompany"
r =requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one(".tableFile2")


for i in table.select("td[nowrap='nowrap'] a#documentsbutton"):
    a.append(i['href'])

print(a)
```

Comment: btw what does the '#' character do when placed after a. Can you just provide some color on your first solution starting with the i.select_one part?

Comment: Select for css selector which faster retrieving data in beautiful soup to find list of elements. To find single element select_one() and ‘#’ for ID attribute. When use ID attribute for css selector it should start with ‘#’ To use class attribute should start with .classname